# Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@75b3ef1a returned null for URL:jdbc for grails app on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, groovy, google-cloud-sql

Followed the steps described here to connect my grails 3.2.9 app to google cloud-sql instance on google-app-engine flexible env

http://guides.grails.org/grails-google-cloud/guide/index.html#deployingTheApp

My grails version is as follows

==> grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.2.9
| Groovy Version: 2.4.10
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_131

My application.yml looks as follows

```
# tag::dataSourceConfiguration[]
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:cloudsql://google/{DATABASE_NAME}?cloudSqlInstance={INSTANCE_NAME}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user={USERNAME}&password={PASSWORD}&useSSL=false
            properties:
```

When I run locally using

grails run-app

the app runs correctly

I run 
./gradlew appengineDeploy to deploy and it deploys correctly

But when I try to open the scaffolded pages in the browser, I see the following error in the logs

==> gcloud app logs tail -s default

```
    ERROR --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 

  : Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@75b3ef1a returned null for 

URL:jdbc:cloudsql://google/{DATABASE_NAME}?cloudSqlInstance=

{INSTANCE_NAME}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&us
er={USERNAME}&password={PASSWORD}&useSSL=false
```

In addition the following error is also seen in the logs

```
    ERROR --- [ Thread-16] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl :

 HHH000478: Unsuccessful: alter table property drop foreign key 

FKgcduyfiunk1ewg7920pw4l3o9
```

Does the HH indicate that it is using the h2 database in production env?

Please help debug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue linked to hibernate. The same error for grails discussed here:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11470

Answer (score 0):

You are using MySQL because as you can see the error code say

```
Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@75b3ef1a returned null for
```

Your problem is that you need to configure the URL with your particular details changing **{DATABASE_NAME}** with the name of your database

you can see how to replace in the example at http://guides.grails.org/grails-google-cloud/guide/index.html#dataSourceGoogleCloudSQL

Comment: Yes. I did change {DATABASE_NAME} with the name of the database. I didn't paste that value here for security reasons.